# spring cloud version Brixton.SR5 with spring boot 1.4

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a new project that we are doing with spring Brixton.SR1...
and Brixton.SR1 or SR5 is built on 1.3.5.RELEASE but forum says it has been tested with 1.4.0.RELEASE and thus i want to use some features of 1.4.0.

```
 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.SR1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
 ..
 </dependencyManagement>
```

And then we are adding dependencies and are all default versions are used eg.. spring boot is 1.3.5.RELEASE, so current structure is as given below.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 ....
```

But i want to use 1.4.0 . Can i exclude 1.3.5 version and use this new version....and i dont want to overwritte this for all spring boot artifacts . eg.. as given below

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and so on so forth..

rather want to have a common version for spring-boot artifact and which should give default versions to all spring artifacts  as 1.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just import spring boot's  1.4 bom and spring cloud's bom into your pom.xml:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.SR5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```